# I can't convert a string comming from getline() to a int or pointer to int in framework arduino for ESP32 after correctly receive de text data

Tags: string, type-conversion, integer, arduino-esp32

how are you?

I'm receiving text from a web page into an ESP32 webserver, the data is numbers sent as text then I need to convert them from string to int, the code is the following

```
uint8_t Extrae_Data(string trama, FechaProg* destino,char sep) {
uint8_t contador = 0;
string lectura = "";
stringstream cadena_leida(trama);
Serial.print("La trama es: ");
Serial.println(trama.c_str());
Serial.print("El stringstream es: ");
Serial.println(cadena_leida.str().c_str());
while(getline(cadena_leida, lectura, sep))
{
    if(sep == '-')
    {
        switch(contador)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                destino->ano = lectura.toInt();
            }
            break;
            .
            .
            .
```

destino is a structure where its members are pointers to int, the problem here is that is impossible to me to convert the content of lectura which has string text -specifically in this case the year- to int format to store it in the structure.

I applied toInt() and the compiler says that string doesn't have the member toInt(), I tried atol() and it isn't work at all.

How can I solve this?.

Thanks in advance for the help.